# KDE 5 - How to easily switch between audio outputs?

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, kde, alsa

I currently have KDE 5 Plasma installed which I like a lot.

However, it is not possible to easily switch between Audio outputs from One Soundcard (SPDIF and analog) like it was possible in Unity.

Is there a way to accomplish this without going to this menu here:

[image]

I need like one setting for each

1. Digital Stereo + Analog Stereo Input
2. Analog Audio Stero + Analog Stereo Input

I want to change them here:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Could you try [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/919033/quickly-change-audio-device-in-kde) , it is for KDE4

Comment: It seems that this user-interface aspect is being redesigned at the moment. There is a blog post that is describing the problem, proposing a solution, and requesting feedback. Do check it out here: http://davidrosca.blogspot.ca/2016/04/audio-volume-improvements-in-plasma-57.html

Comment: Finally I found a good solution see my answer, please remember to  accepted it .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401492/how-to-output-unique-audio-to-multiple-ports-profiles-of-a-pulseaudio-card) I finally found a solution, see the below instruction

**Show always HDMI output in the mixed**
We will create a new profile that link both profiles "Analog audio" and "HDMI audio".

From my understanding this file 
`/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/default.conf` list all mapping profiles between Alsa and Pulseaudio.

**1.**
Find the mapping that are related to your `Analog profile` and `HDMI profile` definition.
(**description:** should match the **Device Profiles** shown in *Audio Volume* Kde setting module )

For me are the following:

```
[Mapping analog-stereo]
device-strings = front:%f
channel-map = left,right
paths-output = analog-output analog-output-lineout analog-output-speaker analog-output-headphones analog-output-headphones-2
paths-input = analog-input-front-mic analog-input-rear-mic analog-input-internal-mic analog-input-dock-mic analog-input analog-input-mic analog-input-linein analog-input-aux analog-input-video analog-input-tvtuner analog-input-fm analog-input-mic-line analog-input-headphone-mic analog-input-headset-mic
priority = 10

[Mapping hdmi-stereo-extra1]
description = Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
device-strings = hdmi:%f,1
paths-output = hdmi-output-1
channel-map = left,right
priority = 2
direction = output
```

**2.**
On the base of the above Mapping definition I have created the following new profile that group both the above ones:

```
[Profile output:analog-stereo+output:hdmi-stereo-extra1]
description = All
output-mappings = analog-stereo hdmi-stereo-extra1
input-mappings = analog-stereo
```

**3.**
Restart pulse audio with this command:

```
pulseaudio --kill; sleep 1; pulseaudio --start
```

**4.**
Go to KDE phonon settings > Audio Hardware setup and select the new profile.
 [image: 2 profiles in the mixer]

Now you should see both profile in the mixed and so you'll be able to switch easy:

[image: HDMI is always shown in the mixer now]
I would suggest to use this plasmoid mixer: https://store.kde.org/p/1100894/

**(extra step) Force both output enabled**

If you don't mind having both computer speaker and TV output audio in the same time ( so basically you don't have to switch the audio output ever ).

You can select the below setting and then you'll have a new entry in the mixer

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As KDE 5 seems to be just frontend for PulseAudio, you can use direct access to PulseAudio with [pactl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pactl) command.

You will have to experiment a little bit to find a correct settings for you exact setup, but I would recommend excellent Arch Linux wiki on [Pulse Audio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio), the [Pulse Audio Configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Configuration) and [Examples](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples).

After figuring the correct commands, create a small shell scripts and create entry for those in `~/.local/share/applications/` (assuming that KDE 5 uses free desktop specification to create launcher for applications -- I am not really sure as I never used KDE).

Answer (score 1):

I searched everywhere ... I did not find ... I made a script in python, use it)

```
import os
speakers = []
st = 0
au = os.popen("pacmd list-sinks")
audiotm = au.read()
audio = list(audiotm.split())
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(audio) if x == "name:"]
for num in range(len(indices)):
    speakers.append(audio[indices[num]+1])
for num in range(len(speakers)):
    speakers[num] = speakers[num][1:len(speakers[num])-1]
dir = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dir = dir[:-5]
try: f = open(dir + "lststate.txt","r");st = int(f.read()) ;f.close();
except:f = open(dir + "lststate.txt","w");f.write(str(st)); f.close();
if st == len(speakers): st = 0;
OUT = speakers[st]
st += 1
f = open(dir + "lststate.txt","w");f.write(str(st)); f.close();
z = os.popen("pactl list short sink-inputs")
OUTID = z.read().split()
x = os.popen("pacmd set-default-sink " + OUT)
for num in range(0,len(OUTID),7):
    y = os.popen("pactl move-sink-input " + OUTID[num] + " " + OUT)
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is now an easier way to achieve this.

- Open "Audio Volue Settings - Plasma"
- Click "Audio Volume" icon on the
- Click "Advanced" tab on the top right
- Change the "Profile:" to
  "All"

[image: Audio Volume Settings, Profile:All]